# Angular pattern validation without form

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I am trying to validate user input (Angular6 PrimeNG pInputText) for specific URL pattern,
lets say  https://something.company.com  maybe on blur.

That field used to be a part of a form, but can no longer be there (that screen is now a part of really complex 6 parts form).  So when the button is clicked, it supposed to get some data related to that URL
from DB and fill bunch of fields on the form for edit.

It is a part of team management app for a bank, so that input field is to enter and validate some resource like JIRA or bitbucket repo.

So how such validation can be implemented?
I've seen someone mentioning ngForm directive, but I don't want to disturb that complex form or have side effects.  Can we have 2 forms on 1 screen?
Will they clash with each other?

Also there is a pattern attribute in input field, so there might be a way of doing it without the form.

Please advise.  Any help is very appreciated.

TIA,
Oleg.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create multiple forms in one page without any issue in angular.
2. You can easily handle this scenario without having form. If you want to use blur you can easily use it like below:

   ```
    <input type="text" pInputText placeholder="url" [(ngModel)]="data.model"
             (blur)="checkInputValue(data.model)"/>
   ```

in component.ts

```
checkInputValue(value: string){
    // suppose value is"https://www.google.com";
    var patt = new RegExp(/^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$/gm);
    var res = patt.test(value);
    if(res){
    //fetch data from db and fill the second form
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting!  But I would need a little more error handling here (like red border for input field, some error message).  Also could you please elaborate on doing it as an Angular form vs. that approach.